# jquery change() doesnt work if the value is changed using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a text input field which i have made readonly so the user can't type into it. I update the value of it with jquery though. So basically I want an event to fire when its value gets changed using jQuery. Below is an example of the input markup and jquery markup.

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="textinput" />

$('#textinput').change(function() {
    alert("It's Changed!");
});
```

Comment: I don't believe there is such an event, since it's reasonable to assume the programmer knows when he is changing the DOM and can call a function explicitly at the same time.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You won't be able to do this.  Changes made through code do not trigger events.  You can simply call `change` directly in your code.

Something like this:

```
// do stuff
$('#textinput').val("something").change();
```

Comment: this should be selected as the right answer. also... it should be noted that every JQ script that involves setting/changing .val() should always tack on .val().change() so the event can bubble up on readyonly and/or hidden elements.

Answer (score 6):

I think the 'change' event only fires when the textbox loses focus. So after changing the value in your code you'd need to do -

```
$('#textinput').trigger('change')
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/upS2x/1/

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a readonly input, you are not able to type in it, therefore, change, keyup, keydown, and keypress will not work with regards to this input.

That being said, you should apply an event to the function that does change the input text. So if input1 changes the text in textinput:

```
$("#input1").keyup(function(){
    $("#textinput").val($(this).val());
});
```

I hope that helps.