# Disabled textbox change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Short Explanation

I want to do something whenever disabled textbox value is changed

Detailed Explanation

I have a disabled text box which value is setting programitically I want to bind the change event of disabled textbox to fire some other function. This is what I tried but won't work.

```
$('#Rate').change(function() {
           // alert("Change Event Called");
            CalculateMedicine();
        });

$('input[id$=Rate]').bind("change", function () {
            CalculateMedicine();
        });
```

This both thing don't work for me and the I don't like the idea to put a function `CalculateMedicine()` to all the place from which possibly `Rate` textbox is changing.So apart from this solution any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you explain what your trying to do a bit clearer?

Comment: In short I want to call a function or do something whener disabled textbox value is cahange

Comment: Is it clear now @ujwaldhakal

Comment: then check the value of that checkbox if disable to ur operation i think u added some class for disable so check the class if the class disable is found call some functions

Comment: No its not a duplicate of it he is trying to enable disable the textbox on click event in my case there wont be any click event. There is only change event of disabled textbox

Comment: No @ujwaldhakal first of all its a textbox and not checkbox and second thing is there is not only one disabled textbox in form i have more then 1 disabled textbox in form so that idea wont be good

Comment: You have to trigger the change() event in your code after changing the text by script.

Comment: Can you please show me a little example for it

Comment: @JavaScript I guess using trigger is somewhat similar to calling a function from all the place which is changing the disabled textbox value right??

Comment: @Snehal: Added you an example below.

Answer (score 0):

The `change` event will not fire if you change the value programmatically

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7878081/3052648

A **not elegant** possible solution:

```
function checkChanges(){
    if(prevRate != $('#Rate').val()){
        prevRate = $('#Rate').val();
        alert('changed');
    }
}

var prevRate;
$(document).ready(function(){
    prevRate = $('#Rate').val();
    setInterval(function(){
        checkChanges();
    } ,500);
});
```

Comment: Using trigger it only fires at page load on not on textbox value change

Comment: @Snehal I was not suggesting to use _trigger()_. I've updated my answer, take a look if you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trigger`for a change event:

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="fname" class="myTextBox" ><br>
<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
```

Javascript:

```
$(".myTextBox").change(function(){
  console.log("yes i m working");
});

$("#submit").click("input", function() {
     $(".myTextBox").val("New value").trigger("change");
});
```

Check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X9AAn/16/)

Comment: This is something similar like to call a function from wherever you are changing the value of disabled textbox

Comment: Yes you are rite.you are not writing in your textbox you are just changing it value programmatically.

Comment: Then its no meaning of using trigger function. Is there any other work around for doing such things or it is not possible to do that kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your your input has disable class on on click or something else you check like this

```
 if ($( "#input" ).hasClass( "disable" )) {
Your logics and codes here //


}
```

//Hope this would help

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if one redefines the value property of that input.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function Init(){
                var tE = document.querySelector('input'); //Our input field.

                //We redefine the value property for the input
                tE._value = tE.value;
                Object.defineProperty(tE, 'value', {
                    get: function(){return this._value},
                    set: function(v){
console.log(1, 'The value changed to ' + v)
                        this._value = v;
                        this.setAttribute('value', v) //We set the attribute for display and dom reasons
                        //Here we can trigger our code
                    }
                })
            }

            function Test(){
                //In one second we are going to change the value of the input
                window.setTimeout(function(){
                    var tE = document.querySelector('input'); //Our input field.
                    tE.value = 'Changed!'
console.log(0, 'Changed the value for input to ' + tE.value)
                }, 1000)
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload = 'Init(); Test();'>
        <input type = 'text' disabled = 'true' value = 'Initial' />
    </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v9enoL0r/

Answer (score 0):

You can fire change event by the following code from wherever you want to fire change event or any other event. The event will be fired either value changed or not. Just place the code after from where you are changing value programatically.

```
element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
```

```js
let input = document.querySelector("input");
input.addEventListener("change", () => alert("Change Event is Fired"));
input.value = "xyz";
input.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
```

```html
<input type="text" disabled value="abc">
```