# HTML5: Is possible disable the change event of the input type number via Javascript?

Tags: html, events, input, numbers, disable

I want disable the default change event of the input number. I don't want to remove the arrows, I just want to customize the value the user will see in input:

https://codepen.io/vendramini/pen/gNbVoe

```html
<form id="myform">
  <input class="number-padding" type="number" required pattern="[0-9]{2}" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

```
(function($) {
  $("#myform").submit(e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    alert("form sent!");
    return false;
  });

  $(".number-padding").on("change", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).val() < 10) {
      $(this).val("0" + $(this).val());
    }

    return false;
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Just tell me if is possible to do it without create a mega input component from scratch or get a entire framework to only do this. Thanks!

---

**Edit:**

The best reference I found was [react-numeric-input](http://vlad-ignatov.github.io/react-numeric-input/) but I don't use React. I accept jQuery libs that does the same thing.

Comment: Maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469401/disabled-textbox-change-event

Comment: @aggaton, thanks for the post. But in my case, we are talking about the input with type number and not the type text, that's completely different. If I disable my input number, the arrows will not appear in my field.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the read only attribute to the input tag and you are good to go

```
<input class="number-padding" type="number" required pattern="[0-9]{2}" value='5' readonly="readonly" />
```

Comment: How I enable the arrows that way?

Comment: The arrows will still be diplayed

Comment: I changed my answer check it

Comment: Same problem. Thanks for the try. But disabled and readonly have the same behavior. The arrows didn't appear for both cases.

Comment: You need to note that the arrow does not show in all browsers. it does in firefox it may not in IE or EDGE

Comment: Ok, works in Firefox, thats good, what about Google Chrome? Anyway, in Firefox the arrows appear but it didn't work, how I will detect the event of the arrows? Shame that there's no HTML solution for this.